# Use Global!.TotalPages Parameter to be sent to stored procedure after report rendering

Tags: reporting-services, reporting-services-2016

I'm trying to update a record in database using the built-in parameter `Global.TotalPages` of a report but I just can't do it.

I've tried to use a sub-report in which I call a stored procedure to update said record, but I can't send the Total Pages variable as a param since I can only use the `Global.TotalPages` in the header.

I've also tried to call the sub-report on header but that's something that can't be done.

Does anyone have any ideas on how can I use the `Global.TotalPages` value to update a record in the database?

PS: I've also tried to calculate the number of pages using the formula:

```
(TotalRowsINResultSet / RowsPerPage)
```

but it's not always exact, sometimes I get 1 less page, other times 1 more page, and other times I get the correct number of pages.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue is that `TotalPages` is only calculated after the body of the report is rendered, so it will not be available for other calculations...

However, you *should* be able to use you simple Expression to calculate the number of pages if you modify it.

Try using

```
CEILING(TotalRowsINResultSet / RowsPerPage)
```

This will ensure that the result of the division is rounded up to the nearest whole number. Your original expression might have calculated this incorrectly. For exmaple, if the total rows was 12 and rows per page was 10, then the result would be `1.2` which, depending on how you tried to get the integer part, might give you a result of `1` rather than `2`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer my friend, i've actually tried it like this and i have some issues with it, for example if i do this : Celing(655/32) = 20.46, and celing gives me 21, but in this case i do have 20 pages so it's givin' me one more, and also with another number of records, begin 32 the RowsPerPage in every page.

Comment: I don't understand how you can have 20 pages with 655 rows if each page can only contain 32 rows? Do you have filters on the dataset which are reducing the actual amount of rows?

Comment: Yes, i have filters on my dataset that can reduce the total amout of rows in the resultset, and i have a space of 32 rows on each page, so when the filter causes the result set returns 655 rows (in this case of course).

Comment: So you mean that the dataset query return 655 rows but the dataset results is less than 655?